# Construir tabla con JQuery con los datos retornados de un JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, symfony3

La cuestión es que en mi código js no se que debo hacer muy bien que debo hacer en la función `pintarTr` y en la función `llenarTabla` para que me muestre los resultados que tengo en el json.

Este es el código js:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var clientId = $("#clientId option:selected").val();
    var clientName = $("#clientId option:selected").text();

    var professionalId = $("#professionalId option:selected").val();
    var professionalName = $("#professionalId option:selected").text();

    validarSelect(clientId, clientName);
    validarSelectProfessional(professionalId, professionalName);
    var alert = 'El informe de condiciones de salud se carga para: ';
    

    $('#clientId').change(function(){

        clientId = $(this).val();
        clientName = $('#clientId option:selected').text();

        validarSelect(clientId, clientName);
    });

    $('#professionalId').change(function(){

        professionalId = $(this).val();
        professionalName = $('#professionalId option:selected').text();
       
        validarSelectProfessional(professionalId, professionalName);     
    });
   
    $('select[multiple=multiple]').multipleSelect({
        filter: true,
        selectAll: true,
        placeholder: labelMax,
        countSelected: '# seleccionados',
    });

    function validarSelect(clientId, clientName){
        if (clientId) {
            $("#clientName").html(alert+""+clientName);
            $("#hreport_clientId").val(clientId);
        }else{
            $("#clientName").html(alert+" informe de condiciones de salud ");
            $("#hreport_clientId").val(null);
        }
    }

    function validarSelectProfessional(professionalId, professionalName){
        if (professionalId) {
            $("#professionalName").html(alert+""+professionalName);
            $("#hreport_professionalId").val(professionalId);
        }else{
            $("#professionalName").html(alert+" informe de condiciones de salud ");
            $("#hreport_professionalId").val(null);
        }
    }

});

$("#btn_consulta").click(function() {
    try {  
        if($("#clientId").val() == ""){
            alert("Seleccione un cliente.");           
        }else if($("#professionalId").val() == ""){
            alert("Seleccione un profesional.");            
        }else{
            var clientId = $("#clientId").val();
            var professionalId = $("#professionalId").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: $('#url').val(),
                type: 'GET',
                data: {                                    
                    clientId: clientId,
                    professionalId: professionalId
                },
                beforeSend: function() {
                    loaderAdmin();
                    pintarTr();
                },
                success: function(json) {
                    llenarTabla(json);
                },
                complete: function() {
                    loaderAdmin(true);
                }
            });
        }                
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error Function buildDataTable: " + e.message + "\nLine: " + e.lineNumber);
        return false;
    }
});

function llenarTabla(json) {
 try{        
        $('#subida_archivoh').css('display', '');


  $('#contentTable').html(tabla);

      buildDataTableMatrix();
 }catch (e) {
        console.log("Error Function llenarTabla: " + e.message + "\nLine: " + e.lineNumber);
        return false;
    } 
}

function pintarTr() {
    try {

        
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error Function pintarTr: " + e.message + "\nLine: " + e.lineNumber);
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Construye las tabla dinamica DataTable
 * @returns 
 */
function buildDataTableMatrix() {
    try {
        var table = $('.dinamicTable').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            scrollX: false,
            scrollY: '50vh',
            footer: false,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            order: [
                [2, "desc"]
            ],
            //paging: false,
            buttons: [{
                //extend: 'reporte',
                footer: false,
                bom: true,
                fieldSeparator: ';',
            }],
        });

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error Fuction buildDataTable: " + e.message + "\nLine: " + e.lineNumber);
        return false;
    }

}
```

y mi html:

```html
<h3 class="blank1">Informe de condiciones de salud</h3>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" style="width: 29%;">
            <select name="clientId" id="clientId" class="form-control"  style="width: 312px;" >
                <option value="">Seleccione un cliente</option>
                {% for client in clients %}
                    <option value={{client.clientId}}>{{client.tradename}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" id="url" value="{{ path('statistics_find_Hreports') }}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="width: 29%;">
            <select name="professionalId" id="professionalId" class="form-control"  style="width: 312px;" >
                <option value="">Seleccione un Profesional</option>
                {% for professional in professionals %}
                    <option value={{professional.professionalId}}>{{professional.name}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" id="url" value="{{ path('statistics_find_Hreports') }}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center; width: 8%;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_consulta" >Consultar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <input type="hidden" id="srcImgLoader" value="{{ asset('assets/images/loader-2.gif') }}">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="contentTable" style="overflow:auto" class="col-md-12"></div>
    </div>  
    
    <table id="Table" name="tabla_vacia" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th col="1" name="id" style="width:100px;">Id_Reporte</th>
                <th col="2" name="hreportFile" style="width:240px;">Reporte</th>
                <th col="3" name="cliente" style="width:235px;">Cliente</th>
                <th col="4" name="profesional" style="width:235px;">Profesional</th>                                  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>    
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br><br>
    {% set x = {'classFormGroup' : 'col-md-12'} %}
    <div id="subida_archivoh" class="row well col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" style="display:none;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <br>
            {{ macroF.start(form, 'Importar pdf', { 'attr': {'class': 'center'} }) }}
            <br>
            <p id="clientName" style="text-align: center;"></p>
            <p id="professionalName" style="text-align: center;"></p>           
            {{ macroF.input(form.hreportFile, 'hreportFile', x) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.clientId) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.professionalId)}}
            {{ macroF.end(form, '') }}
        </div>
    </div>    
{% endblock %}

{% block scriptfooter %}
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/hreport.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Estos son los resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando la libreria de Datatable puedes insertar tu Arreglo de Objetos (JSON) como parametro y automaticamente crea la tabla

```js
$('#TuIDdeLaTabla').DataTable({
    data: JSONArray,
    columns: [
        { data: 'Dato1' },
        { data: 'Dato2' },
        { data: 'Dato3' }
    ]
});
```

Te dejo la documentacion para mas informacion

[Como usar Objetos en Datatable](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Objects)

Answer (score 0):

En to código javascript llamas a la clase `.dinamicTable` , pero en tu html no esta referenciada en ninguna parte, y la tabla en concreto que quieres usar para mostrar los datos tiene como identificador otro diferente:

Código de la función:

```
/**
 * Construye las tabla dinamica DataTable
 * @returns 
 */
function buildDataTableMatrix() {
    try {
        var table = $('.dinamicTable').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            scrollX: false,
            scrollY: '50vh',
            footer: false,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            order: [
                [2, "desc"]
            ],
            //paging: false,
            buttons: [{
                //extend: 'reporte',
                footer: false,
                bom: true,
                fieldSeparator: ';',
            }],
        });

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error Fuction buildDataTable: " + e.message + "\nLine: " + e.lineNumber);
        return false;
    }
```

Cabecera de la tabla:

```
<table id="Table" name="tabla_vacia" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" >
```

Un saludo !